# error al desplegar un servicio resftul

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, restful

Tengo un servicio RESTful creado en Netbeans que coje los datos de una base de datos remota que tengo en mysql. He seguido los pasos de esta web: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html (en este ejemplo crean una base de datos. Yo ya la tengo creada en el servidor remoto que tengo virtual). En local me funciona bien, pero cuando lo desplego en el servidor remoto Glassfish me sale un error:

```
> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app
> [ProjecteRepairManage] : Class service.PrioritatFacadeREST has
> unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than
> those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_80. Please
> see server.log for more details.
```

El código de la clase service.PrioritatFacadeREST es:

```
package service;

import entities.Prioritat;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@Path("entities.prioritat")
public class PrioritatFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Prioritat> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ProjecteRepairManagePU")
private EntityManager em;

public PrioritatFacadeREST() {
    super(Prioritat.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void create(Prioritat entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Prioritat entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Prioritat find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Prioritat> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Prioritat> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

}
```

Entiendo que me dice que la versión Java no es correcta. El ordenador donde estoy trabajando tiene la versión Java 1.8. Si la cambio a la 1.7 me da exactamente el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te dice es que has pasado a una JVM versión 7 clases compiladas para el JVM 8. Como el JVM 7 no sabe si las clases serán compatibles, protesta.

Lo que tienes que hacer es compilar tus clases con indicando que quieres que te genere las clases para el JVM 7.

Tienes que ir a `Project -> Properties -> Sources window` y poner el valor a 1.7.

Si quieres saber en qué versión está compilada una clase, puedes usar la herramienta `javap`; Java 7 tiene el "version-number" 51 y Java 8, 52.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Comment: Tengo que cambier el valor de Source/Binari format, no? Y como uso la herramienta javap? No la conozco. Gracias.

Comment: a) basta `javap -v [clase]` y ya está, hay mucha información sobre la herramienta. b) Me alegro de haber solucionado tu problema (deberías marcar la respuesta como correcta); si tienes otro problema nuevo deberías abrir una pregunta independiente.